# Mapping extra rows on a Doctrine 2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

The thing is, my users have ratings that are averaged through an MtM relation, e.g. a `User` has many `Ratings` and the average of `Rating` entity field values is the user's rating.

What I want to do is figure out a way to somehow put this data into the user model, into a virtual field or whatnot. I've managed to create a non-mapped property and accessor methods for it, so that the interface is solid and my views look good. The property is not mapped in Doctrine obviously.

And then seems like I've digged through every Doctrine internal. I've looked through hydrators and ResultSetMappings, yet there seems no good way to push a calculated field into the entity field.

So, here's what I've managed to come up with.

This is where I join and select the extra field:

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->addSelect('AVG(r.rating) AS people_rating')
    ->from('MyMainBundle:User', 'us')
    ->leftJoin('u.reviews', 'r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.user = u')
    ->where('u.id = :id')
    ->orderBy('people_rating', 'DESC')
;
```

What I need to get is Doctrine pushing the `people_rating` into the `User` entity somehow. Now I get an ugly array looking like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    class My\MainBundle\Entity\User#868 (46) {
      protected $id =>
      int(247)
      protected $email =>
      string(28) "june68@goldneroconner.com.lc"
      private $createdAt =>
      class DateTime#973 (3) (...)
      private $firstName =>
      string(8) "John"

      (more elements)...
    }
    'people_rating' =>
    NULL
  }
}
```

And here's what I really need:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class My\MainBundle\Entity\User#868 (46) {
    protected $id =>
    int(247)
    protected $email =>
    string(28) "june68@goldneroconner.com.lc"
    private $createdAt =>
    class DateTime#973 (3) (...)
    private $firstName =>
    string(8) "John"

    private $peopleRating => (...)
    (my float calculated within MySQL's AVG())

    (more elements)...
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure there's a way to implement a `ResultSetMapping` that would do this, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ugly workaround would look like that:

```
foreach ($usersDirty as $user) {
            $user[0]->setPeopleRating($user['peopleRating']);
            $users []= $user[0];
        }
```